# DualShock 4 V2 vibration/rumble

Tags: gamepad, joystick

I borrowed a dualshock 4 V1 a few days ago and after checking everything was working ok I decided to get one, so I bought a v2. I found out everything works fine except for vibration. Is it still not supported or am I doing something wrong?.
I'm running 4.8.0-2 kernel. My udev rules are the ones from [steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/353370/discussions/0/490123197956024380/).
Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally got it working:

1. You MUST have kernel >=4.10
2. Disable steam's support for DS.
3. Udev rules (the ones from steam):

sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/99-steam-controller-perms.rules

```
# This rule is needed for basic functionality of the controller in Steam and keyboard/mouse emulation
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", MODE="0666"

# This rule is necessary for gamepad emulation; make sure you replace 'pgriffais' with a group that the user that runs Steam belongs to
KERNEL=="uinput", MODE="0660", GROUP="YOUR_USERNAME", OPTIONS+="static_node=uinput"

# Valve HID devices over USB hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="28de", MODE="0666"

# Valve HID devices over bluetooth hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", KERNELS=="*28DE:*", MODE="0666"

# DualShock 4 over USB hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="05c4", MODE="0666"

# DualShock 4 wireless adapter over USB hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0ba0", MODE="0666"

# DualShock 4 Slim over USB hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", ATTRS{idProduct}=="09cc", MODE="0666"

# DualShock 4 over bluetooth hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", KERNELS=="*054C:05C4*", MODE="0666"

# DualShock 4 Slim over bluetooth hidraw
KERNEL=="hidraw*", KERNELS=="*054C:09CC*", MODE="0666"
```

Trigger a refresh of UDEV rules:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
```

3. If mapping is messed out, you'll probably need the correct mapping, controllermap is needed for that purpose:

   sudo apt-get install build-essential xorg-dev libudev-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libopenal-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libaudiofile-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev zlib1g-dev libdirectfb-dev

download sdl 2.0.2 (woking on ubuntu 17.04):

```
cd
cd Downloads
wget https://libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.2.zip
unzip SDL2-2.0.2.zip
cd SDL2-2.0.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd test
./configure
make
./controllermap
```

follow on screen instructions, use backspace key if you mess up an input.

Then you should get something like:

```
050000004c050000cc09000000810000,Wireless Controller,platform:Linux,x:b3,a:b0,b:b1,y:b2,back:b8,guide:b10,start:b9,dpleft:h0.8,dpdown:h0.0,dpdown:h0.4,dpright:h0.0,dpright:h0.2,dpup:h0.0,dpup:h0.1,leftshoulder:h0.0,leftshoulder:b4,lefttrigger:a2,rightshoulder:b6,rightshoulder:b5,righttrigger:a5,leftstick:b7,leftstick:b11,rightstick:b12,leftx:a0,lefty:a1,rightx:a3,righty:a4,
```

Let's use this for grid autosport, for example:

```
gedit ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/GRID Autosport/share/controllermapping.txt
```

add the result from controllermap at the end.

Done.

I have to test it on other games. Working fine on grid autosport so far.